# Facing redirection issue while setting up Wordpress with Nginx via Amazon API Gateway and Network Load Balancer

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, amazon-elb, aws-api-gateway

Facing redirection issue while setting up Wordpress with Nginx via Amazon API Gateway and Network Load Balancer.
Description:-
We have our main website xyz.com(served by Amazon API Gateway and Load Balancer) and want our blogs to be present on xyz.com/blogs.
So, we have set up Amazon API Gateway and Load Balancer to redirect any request of the for xyz.com/blogs to the EC2 containing Wordpress with Nginx.
Problem:-
The problem that we are facing is, the home page is rendered fine but when we try to render any other page, e.g:- **xyz.com/blogs/my-first-post/** or **xyz.com/blogs/wp-admin** then it gets stuck over there and nothing comes as response. As a part of our initial debugging, we found out that Wordpress is making redirections to the Network Load Balancer url, (which as per our guess) is not accessible and we are not getting any response.
This is how our default nginx conf looks like (/etc/nginx/conf.d/xyz_blogs.conf), which we got from this link => [Wordpress|Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/)

```
# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for php
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name xyz.com;
        ## Your only path reference.
        root /var/www/html;
        ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

How shall we resolve this issue?
A prior thanks for any help given hereby.

Comment: check security group to allow LoadBalancers to access your app. `server_name xyz.com;` you may need to add "_"

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX

Network Load Balancer is able to access the app. Also, adding "_" didn't change anything. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thy this:

```
upstream php-app { # <-- change name of the upstram
        # server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket; # <-- Remove this
        # List of [IP:Port] OR list of [sockets] not both mixed

        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # server 127.0.0.1:9001; # example
        # server 127.0.0.1:9002; # example
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;       # <-- Add this line
        listen [::]:80 default_server;  # <-- Add this line

        server_name xyz.com *.xyz.com;

        root /var/www/html;
        # index index.php;    # <-- Will be removed, you app is provided by the socket/port

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location / { # Put this at the end, NGinx apply priority
                proxy_pass http://php-app; # Add this line
        }
}
```

**Update 1:**

update config

```
    ...
    server_name xyz.com *.xyz.com *.amazonaws.com;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX->
After doing the changes, I am getting below error.


`2020/02/28 11:06:13 [error] 6613#6613: *3400 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: ****(IP), server: xyz.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "xyz-blogs-nlb-someNLBGuid.elb.aws-region.amazonaws.com"
`
And the page is giving `502 Bad Gateway nginx`

Comment: Update1: add `*.amazonaws.com` on server_name and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late post, but currently we have implemented this using a solution which might not be much scalable. What we have done is we have deployed our website and wordpress in the same machine but in a different containers. So, our website is running in a different container and wordpress is running in a different container but both are present in the same EC2.
And we are using nginx configuration in wordpress to redirect the requests to the fellow container. Currently my nginx configuration looks something like this:

```
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    index index.php;

    location /blog  {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
    }

    location /  {
            rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass  http://xyz-container:80;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

It would have been great if somehow we would have been able to deploy wordpress container in a different EC2 and still achieve this.
It will really be helpful and a lot better if someone can suggest a better scalable working solution for the problem with wordpress container in a different EC2.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a different question or is it a solution for the posted question?

Comment: @Cristik
This is the solution for the posted question which I have currently implemented.
But a better solution is always welcome :)